# linux bridge vlan-aware and untagged traffic

Tags: linux, linux-networking, systemd, bridge, systemd-networkd

I have the following use case. A machine which runs VMs that have to be located to a VLAN with ID 166. The traffic must go out of an physical interface `enp89s0` which is connected to the primary network non-tagged traffic. For such use cases in Linux a bridge helps to connect stuff together. The machine uses a Linux distro so I use `netword` to configure the network interfaces. Here my attempts:

`br0.netdev`

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
[Bridge]
DefaultPVID=1
STP=no
VLANFiltering=yes
```

`br0.network`

```
[Match]
Name=br0
[Network]
VLAN=enp89s0
VLAN=eth166
[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=1
[BridgeVLAN]
VLAN=166
```

I have considered that the default lan has `VLAN=1`.

The problem is that when I apply this configuration the `enp89s0` interface loses IP addresses and get unreachable.

So my question here is how to have a bridge configured properly that deal with a VLAN and a network untagged.

Comment: What I'm doing is exactly what described in here https://serverfault.com/a/1111805 what I do not understand is how to let that the physical interface receive the ip address

Answer (score 2):

when you place a physical interface to a bridge, you don't configure IP-related parameters on it anymore, the interface basically disappears. In a usual case, it is the bridge which will receive ip address/mask for that interface. In case of vlan-aware bridge, you configure a vlan interface on top of that bridge with the neecessary vid and ip/mask.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in how to setup the VLAN-aware bridge with "management" (untagged) IP address. It is not necessary to have a virtual interface over the bridge. It is just sufficient to have a default/native VID (= VLAN ID with enabled PVID option) with untagged egress set on the bridge, e.g.

```
bridge vlan add dev br0 vid 100 pvid untagged self
```

and the same default VID enabled for all interfaces from which the bridge IP should be available, e.g.

```
bridge vlan add dev eth0 vid 100 pvid master
```

Note: It is not necessary to have the untagged egress set for the default VID on eth0.